# FCM push notification not received

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

hi i had included the following code to receive push notification from FCM server InstanceId is available and the FCM console shows Completed push notification but no function is being called in the app delegate. please help what i am missing

```
func registerForPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(grant, error)  in
            if error == nil {
                if grant {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                } else {
                    //User didn't grant permission
                }
            } else {
                print("error: ",error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    } else {
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .InstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType() {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        self.isNotificationEnabled { (isEnabled) in
            if isEnabled{
                print("Push notification enabled")
            }else{
                print("Push notification not enabled")
            }
        }
    }
}

func isNotificationEnabled(completion:@escaping (_ enabled:Bool)->()){
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings: UNNotificationSettings) in
            let status =  (settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized)
            completion(status)
        })
    } else {
        if let status = UIApplication.shared.currentUserNotificationSettings?.types{
            let status = status.rawValue != UIUserNotificationType(rawValue: 0).rawValue
            completion(status)
        }else{
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    Messaging.messaging()
        .setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.unknown)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Registration failed!",error.localizedDescription)

}

func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
}


Extensions for app delegate 

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary
     print("userinfo",userInfo)
}
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
}
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
 }
```

By this above code i get instanceID generated and i have also uploaded the .p8 file with app prefix and key. when i send a push notification its status becomes completed but no function is being called in the app delegate

Comment: can you add push notification certificate in your app?

Comment: i had added, since it didn't worked i added auth key

Comment: you need to add like setting-> cloud messaging -> APNs Authentication Key or APNs Certificates one of them?
can you add that??

Comment: @SagarBhut yeah i had added the development and production p12 files

Comment: @SagarBhut Thanks Dude.. now its working.. i tried deleting the GoogleServiceInfo.plist and included it again.. it worked.. thanks a lot for you help

Comment: hmm so problem in old info.plist file..

Comment: yes dude.. thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks @SagarBhut, made me look at my config again, had multiple targets and the google-services files weren't assigned to the right ones.